# How can I run background activity?

Tags: android, service, background, background-service

I have a simple chat application, and I want to have the ChatActivity run on the backplane and get a notification when the data is retrieved from the database. But I did not understand how the background would operate.

In the final CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,mesajList,firebaseUser);..... section, the message is received and displayed on the screen. I want this to work in the background

```
public class SohbetActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private static String PREFS = "PREFS";
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 400;
TextView tvBaslik;
EditText et_mesaj;
FloatingActionButton buttonGonder;
ListView lv_chatyap;
FirebaseDatabase database;
FloatingActionButton imageButton;

private AdView mAdView2;

DatabaseReference dbRef;

FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
StorageReference storageReference;

public static final int RC_SELECT_IMAGE=1;
final FirebaseUser firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sohbet);
tvBaslik= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBaslik);
et_mesaj= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMesaj);
    buttonGonder= (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonMesajGonder);
    lv_chatyap= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewChatYap);
    lv_chatyap.setDivider(null);
lv_chatyap.setDivider(null);
    et_mesaj.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.toString().trim().length()>0){
                buttonGonder.setEnabled(true);}
            else{
                buttonGonder.setEnabled(false);}
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });

    String oda= getIntent().getStringExtra("odaKey");
    tvBaslik.setText(oda);

    final ArrayList<Mesaj> mesajList=new ArrayList<Mesaj>();

    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dbRef=database.getReference("chats/"+oda);

    firebaseStorage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference=firebaseStorage.getReference("chatImages/"+oda);

    buttonGonder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String gonderen=firebaseUser.getEmail();
            String mesaj=et_mesaj.getText().toString();

            String zaman = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM HH:mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

            dbRef.push().setValue(new Mesaj(gonderen,mesaj,zaman,null));
            et_mesaj.setText("");

        }
    });

    final CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,mesajList,firebaseUser);
    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mesajList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                mesajList.add(ds.getValue(Mesaj.class));

            }
            lv_chatyap.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

`

Comment: you need to implement a background service to listen for the change. look into "broadcast".

Comment: I added the backplane seems to be working on the device but I can not get the data when it is in the backplane. I want to create a messaging service running on the backplane. I created a backend service as a simple daemon, and when I entered this class, I sent toast to the screen

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to look into.

1. JobScheduler
2. Broadcast
3. Broadcast Receiver

Here is the flow.

- Store the current number of objects in your DB in Shared Pref.
- Create a JobScheduler to go out and look to see if the DB changes based off the current size in Shared Pref.
- If it changed, send out a broadcast to your application.
- The BroadcastReceiver will receive that broadcast and then push out a notification to the user.

Comment: Thank you, I'm searching for two days. But I'd like to ask you something. Can I not send notifications without creating JobScheduler? I read something about real time notification. Can I not send an automatic real-time notification when the data in the Firebase database changes? Is there a source I can investigate?

Comment: If you use a third party notification such as OneSignal. You can schedule notifications on there. But, again, you dont have much control over this in terms of data changing in the database. You need some sort of ticker that keeps track of what is there, go run new code, if the numbers different send out a broadcast. It will be your easiest and best bet.